# Issue submitting a mobile app to App Center

Tags: facebook

I've filled out all of the basic details for my app under the settings tab on the FB developer dashboard. I've ensured that the Native iOS App option has been selected and have filled out all of the relevant details (Bundle ID, App Store ID etc.). 
Next, I click on the App Details tab and fill out all of the information on that page and then click on the 'Submit App Detail Page' button. Upon doing so, I receive an error stating 
"Invalid Submission
Before setting up your app detail page, you must specify how your app integrates with Facebook. Click here to vist your apps settings page to manage your integrations." Clicking on this link simply takes me back to the basic settings page which I have already filled out. I've searched for the app on App Center and can confirm that it hasn't been added to the directory.

Comment: Did you configure your iOS and Android settings correctly? Save those first and check that they saved correctly before going to the App Details tab